# MusicPlayer in Android status bar

Tags: android, android-service, android-music-player, android-statusbar

I have an Android app which plays mp3 files. I have programmed its main functions like play/pause forward, backward buttons, manipulating by SeekBar, getting current position and so on. Now I want to make my app to continue playing even I closed my app. And when I close it, I want to appear thing like widget in status bar with basic actions (displaying app icon, track name, play/pause button). And also, I want to SeekBar work properly when I reopen my app. Can anyone help me. I'm beginner in Android Java, so it would be perfect if your answer contains steps. Thanks beforehand

Comment: are u running music in service?

Comment: Use this tutorial 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778

Comment: Read about the foreground services in android. It has good example about what you intend to make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this tutorial perfectly match your query

[Android custom notification for music player Example](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/08/android-custom-notification-tutorial/)

Comment: I think this website is down now. Any other link?

Answer (score 1):

It think you need to read this articles:

1) https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=ru - this articles can help you to play music on background. It's very important component of youar app;

2) If you want to provide a widget - just see this article https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html?hl=ru

3) If you want to show notification in status bar, see - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Also, you can find many iteresting solutions and lessons here - http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/164-urok-99-service-uvedomlenija-notifications.html

https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/index.html?hl=ru - an interesting article about music players by Google Android Developers

Best regards,
Skidan Oleg